# How to suppress a key while using keyboard.is_pressed?

Tags: python

My code is like

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
```

Then do x stuff, how can I suppress the "*" from being sent to other applications? I want to be like it was never pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CHARACTER == keyValue)
 DO NOTHING
else
 DO SOMETHING WITH CHARACTER
```